# emacs org-mode automatically latex export multiple subtrees to separate files

Tags: emacs, export, latex, org-mode

I have a subtree that I want to export as a latex document. That subtree needs a fairly long preamble specific to it, so I want to compile the preamble into a separate file, which I can then call with `\input` during export.

Right now, I can get the desired result with this sort of document

```
* Exporting with a file input for export-latex-header
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER: \input{stylefile}
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: Main
:END:

content of the main file

** style file                                                     :noexport:
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: stylefile
:END:
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\usepackage{xyz}
\usepackage{abc}
#+END_EXPORT
```

I then perform two exports.

1. I export the subtree `**style file` with the body-only option
   (selected from the export dispatcher), which gives me the file
   `stylefile.tex` as output with the two lines of LaTeX.
2. I export the
   subtree `* Exporting...` in the regular way, giving me `Main.tex`
   with the correct preamble, and during compilation, the `\input`'ed
   lines are compiled correctly.

Is it possible to automate the export process somehow, so that when I export the Main file, org-mode automatically exports the dependency, as well?

FWIW: I've tried defining a macro in org that expands to the desired pre-amble, but macro invocations in `:EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER:` are treated as verbatim, i.e., not expanded during export.

Comment: I would look into [tangling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html#Extracting-source-code).

Comment: Why do you need to do two exports *every time*? Are you planning to change the content of `stylefile` frequently?  Doing the first export produces the artifact that you need for the second one, so you do not need to repeat it unless you change the contents of the style file.

Comment: Agreed on the point---I'm asking this question in part because I will need to do this sort of structure for various documents (think a series of handouts for a lecture course), and it'd be nice to know how to do this in a general way.